# how can i use TYPE_INPUT_METHOD, TYPE_WALLPAPER to create a view?

Tags: android, view, token

When I use these 2 types to create an Android view, I get the Bad token Error, but it won't happen when I use type like `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, `TYPE_TOAST`.
I know there is a token checking mechanism when I want to add view to the WMS. So I don't want to see any source code about this error. I just want to know what should I do if I want to add a view which is the TYPE of `TYPE_INPUT_METHOD`, `TYPE_WALLPAPER`?